# Virtualize pfSense on VMware

Tags: network, pfsense, vmware, gateway

I'm making a network model and I have issues with virtualization of pfSense under VMware.

I have a client in a VLAN 220 (172.2.20.100/23) trying to ping his gateway (pfSense : 172.2.20.1/23) but it doesn't work as the inter-VLAN routing doesn't work also.

This is a diagram of the network :
[image: Network Diagram]

EDIT1 : I created a 220 tagged port group and added it to one of the pfSense vNIC. 
We have Cisco UCS C220 M5 physical server under VMware 6.7 Enterprise, you think we have a driver issue ? 
Our pfSense run under AMD64 (pfSense 2.4.4-p3). 
I tried to use E1000e NIC in VMware but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Where are you doing the untagging? ESXi or pfsense?

Comment: Hi, I resolved my issue by using only one E1000e VMNIC tagged in the 4095 (trunk) instead of one interface by VLAN.

Comment: @PiKeTemplar Sorry, I thought you had that already...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by using 1 E1000e VMNIC on the VM, associated it to the LAN port-group (tagged 4095) and used subinterfaces on pfSense.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that VLAN 220 is assigned as untagged to the client port and as tagged on the host trunk, you need to set up a port group on the host, configure it for VLAN 220 tagged and connect it to one of the pfSense's vNICs.

Running a virtual VLAN trunk from the physical host NIC to the vNIC (=get tagged frames into the VM) can be a major pain (use port group VLAN ID 4095 for *all VLANs*), depending on the flavor and driver for the pNIC and the type of vNIC (only ever works with Intel) and its guest driver.

Comment: I created a 220 tagged port group and added it to one of the pfSense vNIC.

We have Cisco UCS C220 M5 physical server under VMware 6.7 Enterprise, you think we have a driver issue ?

Our pfSense run under AMD64 (pfSense 2.4.4-p3).

I tried to use E1000e NIC in VMware but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used "major pain". The reliable method is to use a port group & guest vNIC for each VLAN and forget about tagging into the VM.